# How do I implement Sized, Serialize/Deserialize functions on Any and Send Traits?

Tags: rust, serde

I got an issue while implement serializing/deserializing and sizing functionalities on a struct that have complex data types like `Arc` pointers `Mutex` locks. First I've resolved these `Arc` and `Mutex` serialization/deserialization problem using this topic:

[How do I serialize or deserialize an Arc<T> in Serde?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49312600/how-do-i-serialize-or-deserialize-an-arct-in-serde)

but now, I got stuck on implementing `ser`/`desr` and sizing for `Any` and `Send` traits, and I have neither an idea nor a compiling example to solve this issue.

Code is here:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_json;

use serde::Serialize;
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::any::Any;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Message {
    pub id: u64,
    pub data: Arc<Mutex<Any + Send>>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Data {
    pub name: String,
}

impl Data {
    fn new(name_parameter: String) -> Data {
        let data = Data {
            name: name_parameter,
        };
        data
    }
}

fn main() {
    let msg: Message = Message { id: 23, data: (Arc::new(Mutex::new(Data::new(String::from("TesData"))))) };
    let ser_msg = serde_json::to_string(&msg).unwrap();
    let des_msg: Message = serde_json::from_str(&ser_msg).unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", msg);
    println!("{:?}", ser_msg);
    println!("{:?}", des_msg);
}
```

Here is the code in the [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=d72b6d31096a25deabd6536a0ce21873)

It gives the following errors:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn std::any::Any + std::marker::Send + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
  --> src/main.rs:15:5
   |
15 |     pub data: Arc<Mutex<Any + Send>>,
   |     ^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn std::any::Any + std::marker::Send + 'static)`
   = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait>
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `serde::Serialize` for `std::sync::Mutex<(dyn std::any::Any + std::marker::Send + 'static)>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `serde::Serialize` for `std::sync::Arc<std::sync::Mutex<(dyn std::any::Any + std::marker::Send + 'static)>>`
   = note: required by `serde::ser::SerializeStruct::serialize_field`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `(dyn std::any::Any + std::marker::Send + 'static): serde::Serialize` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:15:5
   |
15 |     pub data: Arc<Mutex<Any + Send>>,
   |     ^^^ the trait `serde::Serialize` is not implemented for `(dyn std::any::Any + std::marker::Send + 'static)`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `serde::Serialize` for `std::sync::Mutex<(dyn std::any::Any + std::marker::Send + 'static)>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `serde::Serialize` for `std::sync::Arc<std::sync::Mutex<(dyn std::any::Any + std::marker::Send + 'static)>>`
   = note: required by `serde::ser::SerializeStruct::serialize_field`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `(dyn std::any::Any + std::marker::Send + 'static): serde::Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:15:5
   |
15 |     pub data: Arc<Mutex<Any + Send>>,
   |     ^^^ the trait `serde::Deserialize<'_>` is not implemented for `(dyn std::any::Any + std::marker::Send + 'static)`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Consider reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50021897/1233251), I feel it's close to what you are looking for. However, dealing with serialization/deserialization for `Any` can become [particularly tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44231020/1233251).

Comment: yeah it's close I've already read it before asking the question but actually gives no idea about what we did for the solution, thanks by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this solution as a work around but it should work it out for you i guess.

You have to access the `data: Arc<Mutex<Any + Send>>` then serialize/deserialze data and id separately.

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_json;

use serde::Serialize;
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::any::Any;

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Message {
    pub id: u64,
    pub data: Arc<Mutex<Any + Send>>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Data {
    pub name: String,
}

impl Data {
    fn new(name_parameter: String) -> Data {
        let data = Data {
            name: name_parameter,
        };
        data
    }
}

fn main() {
    let msg: Message = Message { id: 23, data: (Arc::new(Mutex::new(Data::new(String::from("TesData"))))) };
    let _id = msg.id;
    let guard = msg.data.lock().unwrap();
    let msg_data: Option<&Data> = guard.downcast_ref::<Data>();
    let ser_msg_data = serde_json::to_string(&msg_data).unwrap();
    let des_msg_data: Data = serde_json::from_str(&ser_msg_data).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", des_msg_data);
    let des_msg:Message = Message {id : _id, data: Arc::new(Mutex::new(des_msg_data))};
    println!("{:?}", msg);
    println!("{:?}", ser_msg_data);
    println!("{:?}", des_msg);

}
```

Here is the playground.
[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=3356ce3530246b00e99b4d53e8db60bd)