# Serializing sub properties on a struct doesn't seem to work

Tags: rust, serde

I'm trying to serialize the following `Result` object, however I'm getting an error because while it workings for some of the properties, it doesn't seem to work on `path`, even though all of the elements involved have [implementations provided by Serde](https://docs.serde.rs/serde/ser/index.html#implementations-of-serialize-provided-by-serde).

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde;
extern crate rocket;

use rocket_contrib::json::Json;
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Result {
    success: bool,
    path: Vec<Rc<GraphNode>>,
    visited_count: u32,
}
struct GraphNode {
    value: u32,
    parent: Option<Rc<GraphNode>>,
}

fn main(){}

fn index() -> Json<Result> {
    Json(Result {
        success: true,
        path: vec![],
        visited_count: 1,
    })
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5a118960654b550e5bb96a868d98e9d8), although I can't get it to pull in the Rocket crate, it must not be one of the 100 most popular.

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::rc::Rc<GraphNode>: serde::Serialize` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:11:5
   |
11 |     path: Vec<Rc<GraphNode>>,
   |     ^^^^ the trait `serde::Serialize` is not implemented for `std::rc::Rc<GraphNode>`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `serde::Serialize` for `std::vec::Vec<std::rc::Rc<GraphNode>>`
   = note: required by `serde::ser::SerializeStruct::serialize_field`
```

From my understanding, `#[derive(Serialize)]` should automatically create a serialize method which serde can then use. However I would expect it to work for the properties too. Do I need to create structs for all the types and then derive `Serialize` for all of those structs?

Do I need to do something to enable it?

The following crates are in use:

```
rocket = "*" 
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] } 
rocket_contrib = "*"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> the trait bound `std::rc::Rc<GraphNode>: serde::Serialize` is not satisfied
> ```

This means that `Rc` does **not** implement `Serialize`. See [How do I serialize or deserialize an Arc<T> in Serde?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49312600/155423). TL;DR:

```
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive", "rc"] }
```

Once adding that, the error message changes to:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `GraphNode: serde::Serialize` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:11:5
   |
11 |     path: Vec<Rc<GraphNode>>,
   |     ^^^^ the trait `serde::Serialize` is not implemented for `GraphNode`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `serde::Serialize` for `std::rc::Rc<GraphNode>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `serde::Serialize` for `std::vec::Vec<std::rc::Rc<GraphNode>>`
   = note: required by `serde::ser::SerializeStruct::serialize_field`
```

That's because **every** type that needs to be serialized must implement `Serialize`:

```
#[derive(Serialize)]
struct GraphNode {
```